# Previous-next links in Book module

Tags: nodes

I am using the Book core module and book_helper, which is supposed to add some functionality.
However, I can only use book pages and then arrange them in a menu using weight.
How can I get previous and next links?
Also, I would like to show a table of contents, with navigation if possible, and chapters.
Thank you.